# How to be RESTful when implementing a shopping cart

Tags: web-services, rest

I have read through the answers on SO but am still wondering

Say i have a "Cart" resource and I need functionality to 

1. AddItemToCart

2. RemoveItemFromCart

My understanding of being restful says

1. Have a resource `cart`
2. addItemToCart should be like so `PUT /cart/{cartId}`
3. removeItemFromCart should be like so aswell `PUT /cart/{cartId}`. Note I am not using `DELETE` because I am removing something from the cart NOT removing the cart itself

My Questions are

1. Using this approach above, if I wanted to log these calls on the server. How would I know which call is for "addToCart" and which is for "removeFromCart" (without going through cart contents obviously) ?

2. Is there another way to achieve this (addToCart and removeFromCart) functionality that is more RESTful and can solve the logging problem too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'thing' in your cart should have an id -- it's a resource in its own right, so you'd not do `PUT /cart/id` to remove, you'd do something like `DELETE /cart/cart-id/things/thing-id`. The id you use in this delete call should have been returned from the addItemToCart call (`PUT /cart/cart-id`). The `/cart/cart-id/things/thing-id` pattern should be used for updates to that item (such as quantity).

If you only have one attribute on your 'cart' -- it's contents, then you can potentially do away with the 'things' portion of the url and use `/cart/cart-id/thing-id to address an individual 'thing', but this is a matter of taste and requirements. If your requirements are, for example, that you have access to other attributes of cart, say a delivery address, then you'd want something like`/cart/cart-id/address`, but if you've used`/cart/cart-id/thing-id`to address things then the`address`bit would be interpreted as a`thing-id`and you'd be in a bit of a mess. If you use`/cart/cart-id/things/thing-id` then there would be no problem addressing additional relationships from the cart.